# Populate a list based on value in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

So i have a list of employee names and locations.  I have a cell with a location name and want to populate a drop down list with all the employees from that location.
Now I've tried various vlookups and offsets but all of them throw errors and just end up upsetting me.
The names get dumped from a sql query and the file gets overwritten each day with this so formatting it into a table in excel won't work.
The length of the list changes as well as people are hired and fired.
The order of the locations stays the same so I can get some dynamic named ranges in there for each location, however, when i setup a Data Validation List to point to the cell containing the name of the Named Range it doesn't work.  Just gives me the Name
I'll have a file for each location that reads from a main file containing data as well as a sheet of employee names listed under their location.

If i could just pass the value of a cell to the source for data validation list as the name for a named range it would be great but unfortunately passing the cell just gives it one name.

Maybe index could work but i don't see how to have it return more than 1 cell..

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @Owen I'm currently running 2013

Answer (score 0):

Power Query is the perfect tool for this task.  It is included with recent versions of Excel but you'll need to download and install it with 2013.  It is free but requires administrative privileges to install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

You open one of your files in Excel and start a new query
Use Power Query's tools to manipulate the data
Close the editor and load the result into Excel.

It is incredibly easy and intuitive, but the best part is that your actions were recorded as a query - so you simply refresh the query when your data changes.

If your SQL dump is always in the same folder then Power Query can grab it.
Once setup, you can manually click "refresh" ... but it'd be easy to automate.

Long story short:  if you're not using Power Tools then you are working harder and producing less.  You need this tool, do not settle for "no".

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Power Query.  I cannot install addins due to company security policy. But thank you for that advice.

Comment: @Xellinus That literally makes no sense.  It is a fundamental tool of the trade and included with every version of Excel after 2013.

Comment: Ok perhaps but I can't install anything on this machine without admin permissions and for IT to allow it I have to request it through the list of approved items. They're not likely to allow an exception through to solve a single problem for a single person and I'm not going to make a presentation for the VP of IT to okay the addition to solve this problem right now.  But I do want to add it so in the future maybe I can get it in.  Just not now.  Thank you tho.